# Wicket DateTextField with <input type="date"> not working

Tags: java, html, java-8, wicket, wicket-8

I would like to have HTML `<input type="date">` component with date picker and so on.

I cant make it work with Wicket. I need to change the model value on onChange() event **without Submit Form** and I need to show the initial value in input field of the java.util.Date object from my Model, which is not working too.

My code java:

```
IModel<Date> model = new Model<Date>() {
    private Date date = new Date();

    public Date getObject() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setObject(Date object) {
        this.date = object;
    }
};
DateTextField dateTo = new DateTextField("date", model);
dateTo.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println(model.getObject()); <-- it is still null
    }
});
add(dateTo);
```

HTML markup:

```
<input type="date" wicket:id="date" />
```

As you can see, date is initialize as **new Date()**, but in `<input type="date">` I can see only **dd.mm.yyyy** and same as setObject() method. The **Date object** param is always **null** after change.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Hi,

have you tried with dateTo.getValue instead of model.getObject() ?

Comment: Hi, getValue() is undefined. I think, that value of "input type date" should be in "Date date" object, so getObject() should return the frontend value after onChange and same as it should show the "Date date" object with new Date() after initialization, but these things dont work.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML date input fields send the data back to the server in the format `2012-12-30`. So you need to configure the Wicket `DateTextField` to parse that format:

```
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.DateTextField;

new DateTextField("date", model, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/2511197